# can someone help me with a warning a resource failed to call close

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error 'Failed to instrument: android/app/ResourcesManager'. This is probably the reason when I open the app it crashes immediately. There are no other errors but this error in the logcat.
The warning appears only AFTER the first time I use the emulator.
I download the avd again and open it for the first time the code works perfectly
It would mean the world to me if someone can help me fix this issue.

here is the code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText textEmail, textPassword;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView forgotPassword;


    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.exitmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.exitMenuBtn) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you wanna exit UwU :( ?");
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setNegativeButton("Yea", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Nah", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Attach the firebase authentication instance to the change listener
        auth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //authChangeListener will send intent whenever the state changes => whenever user successfully logs in
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                   // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, )); //todo: send intent to missions page
                    finish(); //finishes current activity
                }
            }
        };




//        if (auth.getCurrentUser() !=null)
//        {
//            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GroupChatActivity.class);
//            startActivity(i);
//        }
//        else{

            textEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
            textPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
            forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgetBtn);
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");



            findViewById(R.id.loginBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    loginUser();
                }
            });
        }


    public void loginUser()
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String email = Objects.requireNonNull(textEmail.getText()).toString();
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(textPassword.getText()).toString();

        if (!email.equals("") && !password.equals(""))
        {
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occurred, Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                        }
                    });



        }

    }









}
```

Comment: Is the message that short? If not could you share the entire error message? 

Also, does your app crashes when opening every time, or only sometimes?

Comment: sometimes it doesn't crash il provide the whole message